# Scala ToolBox fails on parsing string containing the 'package' keyword

Tags: scala, reflection

I have to parse arbitrary code using runtime Scala reflection. According to the API `ToolBox.parse(code: String)` should do the magic, but it fails if the code to be parsed contains the `package` keyword

There was an [issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/6657) about it and it should be solved in this [pull](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3007). However I'm using Scala `2.12.8` and still have this issue. Here my code:

```
val toolbox = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()

val content ="""package io.core
        |trait Test{}""".stripMargin

val ast = toolbox.parse(content)
```

That fails with:

```
reflective compilation has failed:

'{' expected.
scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed:

'{' expected.
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.throwIfErrors(ToolBoxFactory.scala:331)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.parse(ToolBoxFactory.scala:306)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl.$anonfun$parse$1(ToolBoxFactory.scala:432)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$.apply(ToolBoxFactory.scala:370)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl.parse(ToolBoxFactory.scala:429)
    at io.sam.core.ReflectSpec.ReflectSpec.$anonfun$new$1(ReflectSpec.scala:20)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf$(OutcomeOf.scala:83)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1682)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture$(TestSuite.scala:195)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.withFixture(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.invokeWithFixture$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1680)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.$anonfun$runTest$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:289)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.runTest(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.runTest$(FlatSpecLike.scala:1674)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTest(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.$anonfun$runTests$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1750)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.$anonfun$runTestsInBranch$1(Engine.scala:396)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:373)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.$anonfun$runTestsInBranch$1(Engine.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:379)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:461)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.runTests(FlatSpecLike.scala:1750)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.runTests$(FlatSpecLike.scala:1749)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTests(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
    at org.scalatest.Suite.run(Suite.scala:1147)
    at org.scalatest.Suite.run$(Suite.scala:1129)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.org$scalatest$FlatSpecLike$$super$run(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.$anonfun$run$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1795)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:521)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.run(FlatSpecLike.scala:1795)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.run$(FlatSpecLike.scala:1793)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.run(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
    at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:45)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13(Runner.scala:1346)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13$adapted(Runner.scala:1340)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1340)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:1031)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1506)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:131)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
```

A workaround seems to be adding `{}` to the package keyword. But it is a workaround and I shouldn't edit the source code given. Furthermore, this workaround resolve the parsing issue, but fails when `typeCheck` the AST as shown below:

```
val toolbox = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()

val content ="""package io.core{
        | trait Test{}
        |}""".stripMargin

val ast = toolbox.parse(content)
toolbox.typecheck(ast)
```

Error:

```
assertion failed: 
  value <local <expression-owner>>
     while compiling: <no file>
        during phase: typer
     library version: version 2.12.8
    compiler version: version 2.12.8
  reconstructed args: 

  last tree to typer: Block
       tree position: <unknown>
              symbol: null
           call site: package <root> in <none>

== Source file context for tree position ==


java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: 
  value <local <expression-owner>>
     while compiling: <no file>
        during phase: typer
     library version: version 2.12.8
    compiler version: version 2.12.8
  reconstructed args: 

  last tree to typer: Block
       tree position: <unknown>
              symbol: null
           call site: package <root> in <none>

== Source file context for tree position ==
```

Any ideas to solve this? According to the pull request the support for `package` keyword should have to be added from Scala `2.11.0`. Is in any way my code wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The issue you link to says that parse was written to work like typecheck, without package support. I wonder why limited package was deemed useful. The workaround for arbitrary code is the compiler API in scala.tools.nsc. You can use the limited support in toolbox by checking for PackageDef and typechecking the trees.